# Simple Hello World, AJAX FOR DJANGO

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

So I have this function in views.py

```
def home(request):
    return render_to_response('proj1/index.html', RequestContext(request, {'variable': 'world'}))
```

Which i want to use for AJAX to display "Hello World";

The ajax function is like so :

```
$.ajax({
url: "/proj1"
type:"GET",
dataType: "html",
success: function(data){
    <h1>Hello {{data.variable}}, welcome to my AJAX WebSite</h1>
}     
});
```

How do i achieve it ?
Thanks !

Comment: If you want to get response from ajax why are you using `render_to_response`, you'd better use `HttpResponse`.

Comment: I prefer to render than to http.. :)

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the 'url: "/proj1" ' is pointing to the url that calls that view.

This tutorial will solve your doubts:

https://godjango.com/18-basic-ajax/

Comment: Thanks for the Tut ! :)